# Which integer data type uses x64 CPU core most efficiently?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, x86-64

Adding up two 32-bit integers and two 64-bit integers takes the same instruction time in a x64 machine, doesn't it? If so, when I use 32-bit integers in a x64 CPU core, the other 32 bits do not do any good, do they? I want to do my calculations inside the largest possible numeric range that would fit in a 64-bit core.
Which data type fits this criteria best?

My candidates are:

- int
- long int
- int64_t
- ... (add if you have another one)

Comment: Have you checked the sizeof(int) on your platform.

Comment: The one that matches your algorithm best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m128i`

`N` 32-bit adds takes as long as `N` 64-bit adds only if you aren't using the SIMD unit.

Comment: Hi Ben, do you have a source I could read for this? You've piqued my curiousity.

Comment: http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=15088 and http://www.springerlink.com/content/998whhq31dvvmj0q/

Comment: @Duracell: [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dh78ez.aspx), [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html), and [Intel instruction set docs](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-streaming-simd-extensions-2-sse2/) Intel's C++ compiler will apparently use these automatically without needing to reference them explicitly in the source code.

Comment: S'ok, it piqued my interest too!

Answer (score 4):

You really can't tell if 32-bit or 64-bit computations will perform identically without some sort of measurement.  While in theory, you can drive twice as many bits through the ALU using 64-bit quantities instead of 32-bit, the memory requirements of your app will increase.  Arithmetic operations typically take one cycle on the CPU.  Accessing memory outside of the CPU's cache can take a hundred cycles, potentially causing a large slowdown when using 64-bit quantities.

Comment: On x86_64 CPUs (AMD64, EM64T) and modern x86 CPUs, the simple arithmetic operations can be executed in with a throughput greater than 1/cycle.  But the latency may be quite a bit more than one cycle.  But you're right about measuring.

Answer (score 2):

### int

<del>By definition it is the type that is most efficient on the processor being compiled for. That is why int changes size on each processor.</del>
<quote>"plain ints have the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment</quote>

Note: Any code is highly dependent on the OS being run. If the OS is compiled with a specific size of int then to maintain compatibility any code built for the OS must remain the same. Thus if the OS manufacturer maintains 32 bit int compatibility the size of int will remain 32 as the default (even if 64 is the same speed).

Hopefully over time the OS manufacturers will update there offering to be true 64 bit.

Comment: This is dogma from a bygone age.  Nowadays `int` is kept to 32 bits even if the 64-bit type is just as fast, so that there continues to be a 32-bit basic integer type.

Comment: That's not necessarily true - int is 32-bit with MS compilers on AMD64 to maintain strong compatability with 32-bit source, rather than the efficiency of 64-bit.

Comment: @ Zack: Interesting I had not heard that from the standards body or the compiler manufacturers but worth looking into. But if you really want 32 bin int you can use `int32_t` http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/utility/types/integer

Comment: This is called the LLP64 model, some background on why Windows at least went with this model is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/31/363790.aspx

Comment: The standard says that "plain ints have the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment". It says nothing about "efficiency", only "naturalness", whatever that means. In practice, I guess not many folks find ILP64 "natural".

Comment: @SteveJessop: I think the biggest problem with making `int` 64 bits is that there is no way to declare variables such that expressions like `x-y > z` will be evaluated using mod-4294967296 arithmetic, other than by cluttering code with typecasts and having the compiler silently generate buggy code if a necessary typecast is missed.

Comment: @supercat: I think I'm missing something. Are you in effect saying that because "traditionally" `UINT_MAX` is `4294967295`, people have become accustomed to making use of the mathematically meaningless `>` operator in the ring modulo `4294967296`, with `INT_MAX` as the discontinuity? That seems to me to bless an extremely dodgy practice ;-) Why did the same argument not prevent 32 bit `int` at a time when people relied on evaluating `x-y > z` modulo 65536? Or is it just that 16 bit `int` is so restrictive that people didn't mind, whereas 64 bit `int` seems unnecessary?

Comment: I do agree though, that promotion to `int` sometimes seriously messes you up when trying to use unsigned types that turn out to be smaller than `int`. For example there is no doubt code out there that assumes `uint32_t * uint32_t` has defined behavior (not so if `int` is >32 bits and it overflows!): I'd guess more than assumes the same of `uint16_t`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Even in the 1980's, I think most people recognized that `int` could be larger than a `short`.  It's much more recent that a "non-quirky" machine could have an `int` larger than a `uint32_t`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: What I think programming languages really need is to have cleanly-separated "algebraic ring" and "number" types.  Arithmetic on "number" types should never be *defined* to behave in any way contrary to the behavior of mathematical integers (overflow might be defined as trapping, or might be UB, but never required to wrap).  Arithmetic on ring types should behave according to the rules of the appropriate ring.  Arithmetic between a ring and a number *of any size* should yield a member of the *same* ring.  Numbers should implicitly convert to rings, but not vice versa.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Much of the confusion surrounding signed and unsigned types in C, I think, stems from the fact that handling unsigned numbers in the easiest way possible conveniently made them work like rings, and the implementers of C recognized that the behavior of such types was useful, but the justification for requiring defined wrapping was never thought of in terms of rings, but rather in terms of "there's no reason machines shouldn't implement it predictably".  Allowing code to specify whether something should be considered an unsigned number or an algebraic ring would ease confusion...

Comment: @supercat: I agree, and even if the language doesn't do that for you I think you should be clear which one an unsigned integer variable is used for in each case. So you shouldn't *use* the fact that it wraps around if you're using it as a number (because a checked numeric type wouldn't wrap), and you shouldn't use `>` if you're using it for modulo arithmetic (because a ring type wouldn't have that operator). Hence my bafflement at your example of code worth not breaking :-)

Comment: ...and allow code to be more portable and efficient.  For example, a program might have two reasons for wanting to declare a variable as `uint16`: it might care about having it wrap modulo 65536, or it might care about having each item take exactly 16 bits of storage.  Depending upon implementation, either of those behaviors might be "free", or might be costly; being able to specify them independently would let a compiler optimize aspects the programmer wasn't worried about.  As for `>` with rings, I wouldn't consider it meaningless, though a ternary operator might be better.

Comment: In any case, I think think languages would benefit from allowing programmers to use different types for different use cases of particular storage formats.  Knowing whether a programmer is using a 32-bit type because modulo behavior is needed, or simply because it's "cheap", would allow better and more reliable code.  Similarly, if a language had distinct types for e.g. "IEEE float", "IEEE double", "short double", and "fast float", it could provide precise IEEE semantics when needed and squawk at unintended type coercions, but minimize typecast clutter in most usage scenarios.  Chat sometime?

Comment: @SteveJessop: PS--Although the relational operators may not make sense on things which are viewed as ring elements, there are three sensible ways to express a difference between two ring elements: as another ring element, as the smallest non-negative number which, when added to the second, would yield the first, or as the smallest-magnitude number which, when added to the second, would yield the first.  The aforementioned code essentially does the second of the indicated operations, regarding the result of the subtraction as a number.